# String doesn't Delete

Tags: android, xml, string

I have a string that is called

```
<string name="Welcome">Welcome to The App [...]</string>
```

I get the error apostrophe not preceded by \

Even if I place an apostrophe, it removes it and gives me the error again, if I try deleting the whole string, when I try to run the app, it comes back, I tried deleting it, hitting save, and it still doesn't work. The string still comes back. I also have a symbol r cannot be resolved error, but I cannot clean the build or resync the gradle without this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are putting `\` in your **string.xml** and not in **values.xml** because when error will come it will automatically open **value.xml** without your knowledge and you will try to add `\` there.

I also face this kind of issue in `android studio`.

Comment: Thank you, works just fine now,, if people are lookin at this in the future, you can use &apos; to insert a apostrophe and put a \ before it, so to put a apostrophe, put      \&apos;